# How to call a image link with an id on php by using csv file

Tags: php, csv, fopen, fgetcsv

I have a csv file with id of the image and the link of the image.
I want to make a php script that call the id and open the suitable image of the id. Now I am using this code to show the csv file.

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    print_r($data);
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

My csv file got only two columns
with ID and Image Link

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by opening? If it local or on atnother server? What do you want to do with it? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to write a script. That I only call the ID and the suitable image should be open. Is on a local server. In website I want replace the old image with new image by calling the ID.

Comment: Open as `fopen`? Show us csv structuce. `id,link`  
`id,link`?

Comment: yah as this id link
one1 http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg
dgsd2 http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/foggygoldengatebridge.jpg
aaa3 http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/PIA07759.jpg
two4 
fdg5 http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/nasas-images-of-most-remarkable-events-you-cant-miss.jpg
bbb6 http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/6986083-waterfall-images_Mc3SaMS.jpg

Comment: Good that you provided csv data, not only structure because now we know that images **arent** local. They are separated by spaces , not by `,`? You want to download theese images to disk or what?

Comment: yeah not by a comma. No the image are as a link uploaded on ftp server

Comment: Maybe you just want to **show** theese images to users? By constructing html like: `<img scr="img link">`?

Comment: I also need the old image thats why I cant put it in the html.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need:

```
<?php
$row = 0;
if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        if ($row > 0) {
            if ($data[0] == '1234') echo $data[1];
        }
        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

$data[0] will be your check for ID, $data[1] will be your image link. I have added the row check to exclude the first row as sounds like you have your first row as the heading.

Replace:

```
'ID_HERE'
```

With:

```
$_POST['id'];
//or
$_GET['id'];
// or however you get your id you want to check
```

Comment: yeah the first row is the heading

Comment: Have you tried the code to see if this works for you?

Comment: do you have spaces or commas for your CSV, if spaces replace "," with " "

Comment: On my csv file there is just 2 columns. And i didnt put anything.

Comment: are you able to screenshot your CSV, open in a plain text editor, if your talking about Microsoft Office, Open Office or Libre Office, the default to a CSV (comma-separated values) is that you have commas between each column, hence its file name, for each row you would have a new line

Comment: is with space not with commma on text file. It not allow me to post the screen shot

Comment: When you open in Open Office (Calc), Microsoft Office (Excel), you will not see the hidden characters behind it. As your on windows open the file in Notepad, you will most likely see its comma separated

Comment: Your using field delimiter (Tab), so i have updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: Have you re-copied the code exactly as-is, make sure you use double quotes around the \t and not single quotes

Comment: make sure you are also updating ID_HERE to the ID you want to show image for too

Comment: I put double quotes, what u mean by updating ID_HERE to the ID you want to show image for too?? Do I have to put the id number?

Comment: For example where ID_HERE was in the code I have changed it to '1234' you can replace this with however you need to check for the id, what are you currently using to check for the ID to get your image? is this the full code you have or is there more?